# equating last value in loop problem in innerHtml

Tags: javascript, dom

forecasts is array who has a 10 elements when ı try to print its work perfectly when ı use innerHtml its giving the last value of items and everything is look same

```
const getOtherDays = (data) => {
  data.forecasts.forEach((forecast)=>{
    for(var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
      items = forecast.day;
      console.log(items)
      day[i].innerHTML = `${items}`
    }
    })
  }
```

Comment: If you set something to `a` then immediately set it to `b` then immediate set it to `c` then it is going to be `c`. What did you want to happen?

Comment: You are overwriting the innerHTML. IF you want to append a string, use `+=`;

Comment: I am making a weather application. I want the items to be synchronized as day1, day2, day3 respectively, but while this is happening, the items should also change. The items here correspond to the day values ​​I pulled from the json. When I do it, all the days show up as the last value.

Comment: İf ı do like you sad its writing the all of them but ı want to like ı sad in last comment @user1599011

Comment: `day.length` what is `day`? Did you mean `forecast.day.length`

Comment: day coming from
let day = document.querySelectorAll('.day');

Comment: So why are you looking over them all in each, you should only be selecting one and setting the day

Comment: I thought I could solve it in a short way by looping it like this. But I guess I couldn't get out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a nested loop. If each element of `data.forecasts` is for a different day, use the index in that array to assign to the corresponding DOM element.

```
const getOtherDays = (data) => {
  data.forecasts.forEach((forecast, i) => {
    items = forecast.day;
    console.log(items)
    day[i].innerHTML = `${items}`
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot,sur :) thats solved

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the elements and setting it to the forecast of the day on every one. You want to select the specific element. The `forEach` index has the index. Hopefully that index matches the day in your elements. Basic idea:

```js
const getOtherDays = (data) => {
  data.forecasts.forEach((forecast, index)=>{
    items = forecast.day;
    day[index].innerHTML = `${items}`;
  })
}
```